# Texture Array, creating the texture

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, memory-management

I'm working on a section of someone else's code and hence have been limited to the amount of modification I can do. Anyway, I'm currently trying to create a texture array and have become stuck with a problem:
What I need to support is n textures being individually loaded and stored as GLubytes in a vector. I then need to take all of the data stored in that vector and store it in a single GLubyte object. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
vector<GLubyte*> vecPixelData;
GLubyte*         puData;

for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfTextures; i++)
{
    GLubyte* pixData;
    LoadTexture(&pixData);
    vecPixelData.push_back(pixData);
}

int puDataSize = nWidth * nHeight * 4 * NumberOfTextures;
puData = new GLubyte[puDataSize];

for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfTextures; i++)
    *puData += *vecPixelData[i];
```

Now I'm sure I'm missing some fundamental points on how to copy memory from `vecPixelData` to `puData`, and if not, can anyone give me a 'pointer' as to somewhere to begin on how to check if puData is actually storing the data required. (I've tried using the memory window but the data in puData doesn't seem to get altered.)

EDIT:
The Solution in the end was:

```
int puDataSize = nWidth * nHeight * 4; 
    puData = new GLubyte[puDataSize * NumberOfTextures]; 

for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfTextures.size(); i++)
    memcpy(puData + (puDataSize * i), vecPixelData[i], puDataSize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you need to use `std::copy`. Something along the lines of `std::copy(*vecPixelData[i], *vecPixelData[i] + imageSize, puData + offstet)` (leaving the calculations of `imageSize` and `offset` to you) inside your last `for` loop.

Comment: If you can use `vector<GLubyte>` for `puData` and a vector of vectors for `vecPixelData`.

Comment: final solution was:

    for(int i = 0; i < pszFilenames.size(); i++)
         memcpy(puData + (puDataSize * i), vecPixelData[i], puDataSize);

Thanks for the help

Comment: This looks wrong. If you are still using the same puDataSize than before you are accessing out of bounds memory on several locations.

Comment: Oops.. sorry you're dead right, what I should've written is this:

`int puDataSize = nWidth * nHeight * 4;`
 `puData = new GLubyte[puDataSize * NumberOfTextures];`
 `for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfTextures.size(); i++)`
  `memcpy(puData + (puDataSize * i), vecPixelData[i],                puDataSize);`



Which looks horrible cause I'm not allowed to post as an answer (am noob to stackoverflow). Should I edit my question to include the answer?

Comment: Thats probably the right course. 
A nitpick: When you changed the value of puDataSize, the name (which was wrong to begin with because it is not a `pu` but an `n` in the style-guide you use) becomes misleading. It should be named `nImageSize` or something like that. And for good measure it should be a `size_t` and since you are not going to change it `const`, too.

Comment: I totally agree, but as I mentioned the code wasn't mine, in fact non of the variable names or types were chosen by me. So thanks, and I'll pass it on, but for now I'll leave it as we could be stuck with some issues later on (e.g. puDataSize has been constantly used as is throughout the project). Thanks for the help @Fabio Fracassi, and I assure you that if the site let me I'd reward you with all the "the answer was usefull"s that I could :)